# How to create a simple installer invoker

Tags: vb.net, windows, installation

Thing is: I have two simple programs (a x86 and a x64 version of the same software) which I download from the Internet. I want to create a CD installer for them.

I only need a small and simple program that "invokes" the setup.exe from the software folder. A simple window with two buttons: "install x86 version" and "install x64 version". Than I could click one of the buttons, the program would call the setup.exe from the right folder, and close itself.

So I could have this structure inside my CD:

```
./setup.exe
./x64/setup.exe
./x86/setup.exe
```

Thing is, I don't know how to write this simple software. I have python knowledge, but to install a whole python interpreter just to open a small window with two buttons is quite overkill.

Is there a simple script (in VB, I guess) that could do this for me? I wrote something like this in curses for linux, but I'm no Windows power user.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new WinForms Application in Visual Studio Express and drag the two buttons on the form. Design as you like. Double Click each button to edit the `.Click` event.

The method to start a new windows process is `Process.Start()`

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender as Object, e as EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    RunAndClose(IO.Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "x86", "setup.exe"))
End Sub
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender as Object, e as EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    RunAndClose(IO.Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "x64", "setup.exe"))
End Sub

Private Sub RunAndClose(filename As String)
  If IO.File.Exists(filename) = False Then
     MessageBox.Show(String.Format("The selected installer {0}{0}{1}{0}{0} could not be found!", vbCrLf, filename), "Installer not found", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
  Else
     Process.Start(filename)
     Me.Close
  End If
End Sub
```

You create a sub `RunAndClose` that actually does the work. You have the filename as a parameter for the sub. Check if the file you want to start exists (`IO.File.Exists`). If so start it and close the application, if not show an error message.

The Button-Subs use the `IO.Path.Combine` function. You supply it with a few parts and it builds a path out of it. You want to use it instead of building the string by hand.